# DozerMapper Cannot map my classes

Tags: java, spring

I have been using dozerMapper for awhile, but I am having an issue to this object.

```
public class RefDocuments implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1218743406159472639L;
   private String test;

   public void setTest(String test) {
       this.test = test;
   }

   public boolean isTest() {
       if ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(test) || "true".equalsIgnoreCase(test)) return true;
       return false;
   }

   public String getTest() {
       return test;
   }
```

When I map this with my persistent class

```
public class TestDocuments extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8113415903134966574L;

    @Column(name = "TEST")
    private String test;
}
```

I am getting test as null when I map but in real persistent object I can get data.

Comment: do you have getters and setters for that field? http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/custommethods.html

Comment: yes I have settter and getter for this field

Comment: the problem is because of method names. Need to annotate @JsonIgnore
and name it not is{{ fieldname }}